# Jira - report on bug resolution per user

Tags: jira

Is there a way in JIRA to run a report to see how many issues were "resolved" by what users and how quickly since the issue was reported? It needs to be per user

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can build arbitrary reports yourself with a [Report Plugin Module](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/Report+Plugin+Module), but my experience is that it's quite a hassle. Note that plugins will only work in self-hosted Jira installations, not in Atlassians hosted service.

Another way would be to [leverage the REST API](http://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/#id170363) in order to fetch worklogs and process them externally.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement needs some clarifications I think. It seems you want to see the number of issues that were moved from some status to another status, or perhaps the last time the resolution field was set to a value (any value?). Then group those results by JIRA user.

A second requirement is to track the time from issue creation to the last time the resolution field was set. Again grouping by user.

I'd try using the Vertygo SLA plugin from Valiantsys to do this. It lets you define custom fields to track the time between two JIRA events such as a field updated or a status changed. I believe it can sum those fields and display grouped results in the JIRA statistics and two-dimensional gadgets.

Reports that group by user often become quite large as the number of users increases.